# AWS Cognito getId "Invalid login token. Issuer doesn't match providerName"

Tags: amazon-cognito

I have authenticated against a Cognito user pool, using the API "InitiateAuth" and received back an id token:

```
{
   sub: "8aec..." ,
   aud:"2gr0fdlr647skqqghtau04vuct",
   iss:"https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_LzM42GX6Q",
   ....
}
```

Then I try to get an ID through the API "GetId":

```
{
   AccountId: "345745834314"
   IdentityPoolId: "us-east-1:fb4d5209-33b1-46e2-923a-8aa206d5c7aa"
   Logins: {
      "cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_LzM42GX6Q": "eyJr...." 
   }
}
```

I have set up an identity pool, and correctly set the Cognito user pool as a provider. But I always get back the response form getId:

"Invalid login token. Issuer doesn't match providerName"

I have tried also changing the provider name in the Logins list to:

https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_LzM42GX6Q

so it exactly matches what the token has in the iss field, but that does not solve the problem, still the same message about the issuer not matching provider name.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Wondering if the "AccountId" field is needed, I don't see it in the Amplify README examples: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/blob/master/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js/README.md

Comment: Tried without "AccountId" and it gave the same error.

Answer (score 6):

Ok figured it out, there is actually an extra set of quotes around the provider name: "cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_LzM42GX6Q"

In the developer console it shows:

```
{
   AccountId: "345745834314"
   IdentityPoolId: "us-east-1:fb4d5209-33b1-46e2-923a-8aa206d5c7aa"
   Logins: {
      "cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_LzM42GX6Q": "eyJr...." 
   }
```

}

Which only has quotes around the provider name, and not other fields, which made me suspicious. I clicked "view source" to see the actual json sent and it was like this:

```
"\"cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_LzM42GX6Q\""
```

I removed the extra quotes and it works.

Comment: Could you explain this further?  I'm having the same error message, but I can't find any double quotes occurring anywhere.

Comment: @CamHart In Chrome developer tools, look in the Network tab and see exactly what you are sending over HTTP. You may have a different problem to what I had.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was an incorrect Region value.

If you're using an Amazon provided region in a concatenated string, make sure to use the `System` version of it:

```
public static Amazon.RegionEndpoint Region = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1;

string providerUrl = "cognito-idp." + Region.System + ".amazonaws.com/us-east-1_XYZ1234";
```